# Writing interface for Matrix

Tags: c++, interface, abstract

I am writing an Interface for Matrix class in C++ 
 So all functions need to be virtual
Now in the below code I have defined a virtual function `virtual Matrix add(Matrix A, Matrix B) const = 0;` 
The problem I see is the class Matrix is not defined. So I am confused should I define the 
class Matrix in the interface ? Or is there a better way to implement the interface

```
class MatrixInterface
    {
    public:
       
        virtual Matrix add(Matrix A, Matrix B) const = 0;
    };
```

---

The updated code that's giving compilation error : 
In Matrix.cpp add method : `member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class memberC/C++(1455)`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MatrixInterface.h"
class Matrix : public MatrixInterface
{
public:
    Matrix *add(MatrixInterface *A, MatrixInterface *B) override{
        // implementation
    };
};


class MatrixInterface
{
public:
    virtual MatrixInterface *add(MatrixInterface *A, MatrixInterface *B) const = 0;

};
```

Comment: Why not return a `MatrixInterface` type? C++ allows covariant return types.

Comment: I guess classes that implement the interface are supposed to act on any class also implementing that interface (including themselves). So why not operate on `MatrixInterface` instead of a `Matrix` class that does not exist?

Comment: But as `add` is a non static method, you would use it like that: `A.add(B, C)`. Is it really what you want?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yeah you are write probably if I am making it non static then I should just have one parameter as argument as the first one should be *this* . Also in this case ideally should I add both `A.add(B)` and `add(A,B)` of these methods in the interface ?

Comment: @eike So you mean since Matrix will implement MatrixInterface I can use MatrixInterface in the argument types. As it will allow the Matrix also to be passed

Comment: IMHO, it would be simpler for future usage to declare an `operator +` that would return a reference to its `this` object: `MatrixInterface& operator + (const MatrixInterface &B);`. That way you would simply use `A + B`...

Comment: @puneeta exactly

Comment: @SergeBallesta that sounds like a `+=`, not a `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the interface type from the `add` method in your interface class, then in the subclass, you can override the virtual method and change the return type to `Matrix` (or any [narrower type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type#:%7E:text=In%20object%2Doriented%20programming%2C%20a,is%20overridden%20in%20a%20subclass.&text=This%20usually%20implies%20that%20the,type%20of%20the%20overridden%20method.)).

```
class MatrixInterface
{
public:
    virtual MatrixInterface* add(MatrixInterface* A, MatrixInterface* B) const = 0;
};
```

Derived class:

```
class Matrix : public MatrixInterface
{
public:
    Matrix* add(MatrixInterface* A, MatrixInterface* B) override 
    { 
        // implementation
    };
};
```

You will need to use pointers to take advantage of [covariant return types](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Covariant_Return_Types).

Comment: Thanks That makes a lot of sense. But I am getting a compile time error - `Matrix.cpp:6:13: error: ‘Matrix* Matrix::add(MatrixInterface*, MatrixInterface*)’ marked ‘override’, but does not override` and `Matrix *add(MatrixInterface *A, MatrixInterface *B) override{`

Comment: ok I think I got it. I was not using `const` in the derived class.

Comment: In my example, I've used raw pointers, but you will likely be creating a new matrix, so should consider using a smart ptr instead.